# submit form on image click html

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I am trying to basically submit my form when the slideshow image is clicked on. I created a form, and have input values with `type="image"`, but realized today that some browsers to not handle value inputs from the `<input type="image">`. What would be the best way to do this?

```
<form method="GET" action="/filtered">
      <div class="slider-wrapper"><!-- innermost wrapper element -->            
        <input class="slide" type="image" style="width: 100%; height: 60vh;" name="category" value="Car Cleaning Products" alt="Car Cleaning Products" src="../public/css/img/car-cleaning-slideshow.JPG">
        <input class="slide" type="image" style="width: 100%; height: 60vh;" name="category" value="Car Cleaning Products" alt="Car Cleaning Products" src="../public/css/img/jan-supplies-slideshow.JPG">
        <input class="slide" type="image" style="width: 100%; height: 60vh;" name="category" value="Car Cleaning Products" alt="Car Cleaning Products" src="../public/css/img/paper-products-slideshow.JPG">
      </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: You could add `<input type="submit" />` with `display: none` on top of images.

Comment: didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Use `method="post"` get is to fetch data not to send data.

I believe this would work

Answer (score 0):

If you do infact want to keep your request method as GET, you can apply an `id` to your `form` tag; then add an `onclick="submitForm()"` to your `input` tags (this would also work with the `img` tag or any at that). We will then define our function in some simple javascript code. Hope I helped!

```html
<form id="form" method="GET" action="/filtered">
    <div class="slider-wrapper"><!-- innermost wrapper element -->            
        <input onclick="submitForm()" class="slide" type="image" style="width: 100%; height: 60vh;" name="category" value="Car Cleaning Products" alt="Car Cleaning Products" src="../public/css/img/paper-products-slideshow.JPG">
    </div>
</form>
```

```js
<script>
function submitForm() {
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: I did this exactly, and unfortunately didn't work still. I did really like this method though, because the way I wrote the backend code I could not submit the form as a post.

Comment: Maybe try deleting your browser history/cache or using an incognito tab. If not that, try using a different browser. I know that this code definitely uses the right behaviour, so it sounds like a local issue.

Comment: tried that too, super strange, not sure why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the `form` method to `POST` will work.

```html
<form method="POST" action="/filtered">
  <div class="slider-wrapper">
    <!-- innermost wrapper element -->
    <input class="slide" type="image" style="width: 100%; height: 60vh;" name="category" value="Car Cleaning Products" alt="Car Cleaning Products" src="../public/css/img/car-cleaning-slideshow.JPG">
    <input class="slide" type="image" style="width: 100%; height: 60vh;" name="category" value="Car Cleaning Products" alt="Car Cleaning Products" src="../public/css/img/jan-supplies-slideshow.JPG">
    <input class="slide" type="image" style="width: 100%; height: 60vh;" name="category" value="Car Cleaning Products" alt="Car Cleaning Products" src="../public/css/img/paper-products-slideshow.JPG">
  </div>
</form>
```